# How to interpret these conflicting results on normality of the residuals?

Tags: residuals, vector-autoregression, diagnostic

I ran a VAR(1) model and got some results. I then moved to "diagnostic tests". The problem is that these tests seem to be conflicting (at least from the way I read them).

The ARCH test shows no sign of heteroskedasticity:

```
ARCH (multivariate)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR_before
Chi-squared = 505.47, df = 500, p-value = 0.4233
```

And also no sign of serial correlation:

```
Portmanteau Test (adjusted)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR_before
Chi-squared = 258.76, df = 240, p-value = 0.1934
```

Yet, a normality test (**normality.test** in R) doesn't seem to agree:

```
$JB

    JB-Test (multivariate)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR_before
Chi-squared = 27.793, df = 8, p-value = 0.0005152


$Skewness

    Skewness only (multivariate)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR_before
Chi-squared = 5.9398, df = 4, p-value = 0.2037


$Kurtosis

    Kurtosis only (multivariate)

data:  Residuals of VAR object VAR_before
Chi-squared = 21.853, df = 4, p-value = 0.0002143
```

How would you combine these findings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Autoregressive conditional heteroskedasticity, serial correlation and lack of normality are all different things (apples and oranges). It is not surprising if some of them are present while others are not.

Regarding the apparent disagreement within the Jarque-Bera test of normality, you see a strong indication of kurtosis that is unlike that of a normal distribution but no strong indication of skewness. Still, it is enough to have one of these moments (skewness, kurtosis) unlike that of a normal distribution to have an indication that the distribution is not normal. And this is indeed what you see: the p-value associated with kurtosis is low and so is the overall p-value, even though the p-value associated with skewness is not low. So there is no paradox.

Comment: Thanks for this. I implied that having homoskedasticity and no autocorellation, I had to have iid errors distributed normally. Would you try other specifications if you were me or these results are pretty good and I shouldn't worry too much?

Comment: @Rollo99, normality is probably the least important assumption for regression models such as VAR. You need it for finite sample confidence intervals and hypothesis tests on coefficients, but under nonnormality you can just use bootstrap for that.